# How to get data for series and categories in highcharts-convert.js from mysql

Tags: mysql, highcharts, phantomjs

I use phantomjs and highcharts-convert.js to render image on server. I have JSON script with the name data.json.

```
{
chart: {
    backgroundColor: '#4A4D4E',
    type: 'column'
}, 
xAxis: {
    categories:  ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<span style="fill: white;">' + this.value + '</span>';
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0
},
series: [{
    name: 'Total Interaction',
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 
        135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    color: 'red'
}]
```

};

I run this script in cmd

```
phantomjs highchart-convert.js -infile data.json -outfile image.png
```

and this successfully generate the image.png but I want the category and series take from another JSON which is the result from execute php script like this

```
 [{"name":"Date","data":["December","January","February","March","April"]},  {"name":"Interaction","data":["99621","148350","107637","113887","103831"]}]
```

Then how can i get this ?

Comment: There is no setting in the highcharts-convert to do so, you would need to add new functionality to the highchatrs-convert or build the data.json, with the required changes from your question, before using in the highcharts-convert.

Answer (score 0):

Read the data from data.json and set an object, e.g. "data".
Read the data from the php and set and object, e.g. "series".
Replace the series in data with the series from the script.
Save the new data.
Call the command line statement with the new data.

```
//  I'm harcoding but you get the data from data.json
var data = {
chart: {
    backgroundColor: '#4A4D4E',
    type: 'column'
}, 
xAxis: {
    categories:  ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<span style="fill: white;">' + this.value + '</span>';
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0
},
series: [{
    name: 'Total Interaction',
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 
        135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    color: 'red'
}]};

// It's harcoded but you must get the data from the script
var series = [{"name":"Date","data":["December","January","February","March","April"]},  {"name":"Interaction","data":["99621","148350","107637","113887","103831"]}];
//  Replace the series
data.series = series;

// save data as data2.json
// call in command line: phantomjs highchart-convert.js -infile data2.json -outfile image.png
```